# Retornar somente uma parte da variável PHP

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte variável:

```
$imagem = "D:\Web\data\localweb\sites\site.com.br\crm\748064485.jpg";
```

Eu preciso retornar somente `748064485.jpg`, porém, não quero e não tenho como usar o `str_replace("D:\Web\data\localweb\sites\site.com.br\crm\", $imagem);` porque as pastas são diferentes a cada envio para o banco de dados.

Como consigo ajustar isso?

Comment: [Explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) tudo! Ou usa [basename](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.basename.php) mesmo...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode usar a função *explode* junto com *end*

```
$imagem = "D:\Web\data\localweb\sites\site.com.br\crm\748064485.jpg";
$cut = explode("\\", $imagem);
echo end($cut);
```